# submitting multiple dynamically generated forms with a single submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have 3 forms.  Each representing a quarter of the year.  Form 1 is past quarter, Form 2 is present quarter and From 3 is future quarter.

Each of these forms is in a for loop meant to display the form 3 times (once for each month).  So at the end of the day there are 9 forms I'd like to submit.  So right now this is what I have.

```
php while loop to iterate through campaign ids stored in mysql
{
<input type=submit>
<div id="past">
   for each month in past quarter
   {
       Form goes here
   }
</div>
<div id="present">
   for each month in past quarter
   {
       Form goes here
   }
</div>
<div id="future">
   for each month in past quarter
   {
       Form goes here
   }
</div>
}
```

The while loop generates Ids that the user can select, upon selecting the are presented with the form UI, where they can select between quarters and fill in date for each of the 3 months in the respective quarter.

So right now I have these 3 divs generating 3 forms each (all the same form).  You can switch between them and all the layout/formatting works.

My issue is how to submit.  I want one submit button to send all values from each of the 9 forms to another php file that will then write those values to a table in my database.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this using php/javascript/ajax.  Or if there is a better way I'd love to hear it.

Thanks,

Comment: Put it all into one form.

Comment: If you need someone to write code for you, please check out Careers 2.0, elance or other service. AFAIK, the expectation on StackOverflow.com is that you have already tried something and it didn't work. Anyway, what you're looking to do is fairly simple with a JavaScript plugin like jQuery which has two functions `serializeArray()` and `ajax` that will do exactly what you need. Also, why not just use one form element and put the divs inside of that; this way you don't need javascript to submit the form.

Comment: To expand on Mark's suggestion, put all the input elements in the same pair of form tag: <form method="POST"><input name="field1"><input name="field2">...<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>. When you hit the Submit button, everything's sent in one request.

Comment: yeah but if each form is the same, how do I differentiate what data is from which form when I get the posted data?

Comment: I have lots of code written, just looking for some direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use a full submit b/c submitting one form will prevent the others from being submitted. So, assuming each has an appropriate action set, you can Ajax submit each with jQuery.

```
var forms = $('form');
$.each(forms, function(index, item) {
    var $item = $(item);
    var action = $item.attr('action');
    var postBody = $item.serialize();
    $.post(action, postBody).done(function (response) {
        // do something with response 
    });
});
```